# Does a `_` receiver on a value (non-pointer) still copy the value?

Tags: go

My question is whether or not a copy of a value is made when a method is invoked where `_` is the receiver.

```
type Foo struct {
  // Many fields, making a large struct
}

func (_ Foo) Test(v *T) int {
  // Here we can't use the receiver but the method is still needed
}
```

So I'm wondering if Go implementations will still copy the `Foo` value when `Test()` is invoked, even though it's impossible to actually mutate the receiver value.

```
var f Foo
f.Test() // Is this making a copy?
```

I would also wonder about the case of a pointer, which is automatically dereferenced by default.

```
var f = new(Foo)
f.Test() // Is this making a copy?
```

I tried looking at the assembly, and I think it may be making the copy, but I just don't know enough to be sure.

---

For details on the situation:

This is an odd case where I can't use a pointer. The code is machine generated and required to cause a type to fulfill an interface while doing some initialization on the `v` parameter. *(The generated code has metadata about the `Foo` that gets set on `v`.)*

So if I make the receiver a pointer, the interface won't be fulfilled for "value" instances. This method will be invoked once for each instance, and instances can sometimes be large and/or created in great numbers, which is why I would like to avoid an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Could check by making a huge receiver type (`type Huge [1e5]int` or whatever), invoking a method like yours a million times, and seeing if it runs noticeably slower than doing the same thing with a smaller receiver type.

Comment: The gc tool chain does not optimize the case where the argument is named with the blank identifier.

Comment: I'm removing my answer unless I get time to check the assembly and see what the actual differences are, since the saving of ~4ns is less than the statistical noise of any real work. In general, CPUs are very fast at copying, so you shouldn't worry about this unless your struct is very very large. In that case just use a pointer, since you won't pay the lookup price if you don't dereference it.

Comment: @JimB, MuffinTop, twotwotwo: Thanks. This is an odd case where I can't use a pointer. The code is machine generated and required to fulfill an interface while doing some initialization on the `v` parameter. (The generated code has metadata about the `Foo` that gets set on `v`.) So if I make it a pointer, the interface won't be fulfilled for value instances. This will be invoked once for each instance, and instances can sometimes be created in great numbers. So it's an unusual circumstance that brings me here today. :-)

Comment: ...if it turns out to be an issue, I may just need to parse the targeted code and determine if it's a large enough value to need a pointer. Would've been nice to see it get optimized away though.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this blog post](http://www.sokoide.com/wp/2014/09/28/golang-calling-convention/), the caller allocates stack elements for return values and the callee populates them.

This leads me to believe that the value is copied and then discarded.

That or a specialized callee would have to be generated in the case of _ receiver

Comment: Thanks, yes it does appear from testing that the value is indeed copied.  Seems like a safe optimization to avoid the copy, but since it's an unusual circumstance, it doesn't surprise me too much that this optimization doesn't exist.